# synchronous and asynchronous calling in angularJS with promise and defer

Tags: angularjs, promise

I created following controller with 2 service calling with services. Second response comes before then first. i want to do like i need first response first and second response second. but i just stuck with async and sync please help me for solving.

Second call is depends on first call. For example if first call returns 10 record then i have to call second web service 10 time taking id from first response. so i use for loop but it is not proper.

### Controller

```
var mycompaigndata = [];

asyncService.loadDataFromUrls($http.get(WSURL + 'api/first/', 
{
    headers: 
    {
        "Authorization":'Bearer <my-token>'
    }
}))
.then(function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});


asyncService.loadDataFromUrls($http.get(WSURL + 'api/second', 
{
    headers:
    {
        "Authorization":'Bearer <my-token>'
    }
}))
.then(function(data)
{   
    console.log(data);
});
```

### Service

```
app.service('asyncService', function($http, $q) 
{
    return {
        loadDataFromUrls: function(url) 
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var urlCalls = [];

            urlCalls.push(url);

            $q.all(urlCalls)
            .then(
            function(results) 
            {
                deferred.resolve(results) 
            },
            function(errors) 
            {
                deferred.reject(errors);
            },
            function(updates) 
            {
                deferred.update(updates);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I got id from first response perfectly just issue is calling second web service in loop with different id.

Comment: Your code doesn't show where the ID is in the first service's response, or where it should be passed into the second service. Just because you can see the IDs doesn't mean we know how your APIs work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make sure the second calls are executed after the first one is finished, put the second call within `then` of the first call. To make multiple 'second' calls depending on the number of results of the first call, use `$q.all`.

```
asyncService.loadDataFromUrls('api/first/')
.then(function(firstData) {
    //assuming firstData is an array of 'x' items, do a call for each of these items:
    console.log('results of first call holds ' + firstData.length + ' items');
    var promises = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<firstData.length; i++){
        var id = firstData[i].id;//you can use this to pass to the second call
        promises.push(asyncService.loadDataFromUrls('api/second'));
    }
    return $q.all(promises);
})
.then(function(results) {
  //'results' is an array of results, the nth item holds the result of the 'nth' call to loadDataFromUrls
  for(var i = 0; i<results.length; i++){
    console.log('result nr. ' + i + ' :' + results[i])
  }
});
```

By using `return $q.all(promises)`, you're avoiding the promise pyramid of doom, and keep a flat structure.

Your service code doesn't need to loop anymore. As a sidenote, you can shorten the code of the service and avoid using the 'explicit promise construction antipattern' (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)) like this:

```
app.service('asyncService', function($http, $q) 
{
    return {
        loadDataFromUrls: function(url) 
        {
            return $http.get(WSURL + url, {
                headers: {
                  "Authorization": 'Bearer <my-token>'
                }
            }).then(function(response){ return response.data; });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Second call is depends on first call. For example if first call returns 10 record then i have to call second web service 10 time taking id from first response

Comment: you can use properties of the 'data' object when doing the second call. However, when you say you need to loop, i.e. do the second call multiple times, you might want to take a look at  $q.all. But that's a different question.

Comment: Sorry. i forgot to add this on my question. Please can give answer of that?

Comment: Great help. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `asyncService` seems completely unnecessary and unuseful.

It sounds like you just need to learn how to chain promises and use `$q.all` correctly:

```
function queryApi(subUrl) {
    return $http.get(WSURL + subUrl, {
        headers: {
            "Authorization":'Bearer <my-token>'
        }
    }).then(function (result) { return result.data; });
}

queryApi('api/first/')
    .then(function (data) { 
        return $q.all(data.map(function (entry) {
            return queryApi('api/second/' + entry.id);
        }));
    })
    .then(function (results) {
         console.log(results);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

put second request inside first request promise:

```
 var mycompaigndata = [];

asyncService.loadDataFromUrls($http.get(WSURL + 'api/first/', 
{
   headers: 
   {
    "Authorization":'Bearer <my-token>'
   }
 }))
.then(function(data)
{
    asyncService.loadDataFromUrls($http.get(WSURL + 'api/second', 
         {
           headers:
         {
         "Authorization":'Bearer <my-token>'
          }
        }))
        .then(function(data)
        {   
         console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Second call is depends on first call. For example if first call returns 10 record then i have to call second web service 10 time taking id from first response

Comment: when you write second call in the first call promise the second call will wait for first call and you can use first request data for second request

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is to use loop since you need to iterate the response to get the id.

```
asyncService.loadDataFromUrls(WSURL + 'api/first/')
    .then(function(data) {
         //iterate to get the id
           //call service again
            asyncService.loadDataFromUrls(WSURL + 'api/first/')
                .then(function(data) {
                     //code here
                });
     });
```

**Service**

```
app.service('asyncService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
         loadDataFromUrls: function(url) {
              return $http.get(url, {
                  "Authorization":'Bearer <my-token>'  
              });
         }
    };
});
```