# How to use multiple functions to make work synchronously in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, promise, synchronous

This is my function:

```
$scope.saveManualResendDraft = function(todo) {
    if ($scope.editMode) {
        updateStartJobManual();
        byeSendManualInputDirectly();
    } else {
        console.log('bye');
    }
};
```

I have two functions **updateStartJobManual()** and **byeSendManualInputDirectly()**.

I want to complete first function fully then i need to move to second, How to do? is it possible to do using promises? I need some piece of code.

```
function byeSendManualInputDirectly() {
    if ($window.confirm("Do you want to send this messages?"))
        addProfSms();
    else
        console.log('no');
}

function addProfSms() {
    $http.post('/api/sendprofsms', $scope.draft).then(function(response) {
        swal("Good job!", "Message sended!", "success")
        //  $state.reload();
    });
}

function updateStartJobManual() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/updatestartjobmanual',
        data: $scope.draft
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.currentItem = response.data;
        $scope.todos[$scope.currentItemIndex] = response.data;
        $scope.editMode = false;
        console.log('draft:', response.data);
        $state.reload();
        // toastr.success('Updated Successfully');
    }, function(response) {
        console.log('error');
    });
}
```

Comment: Simple solution : execute the first funciton, and at the end of it, call the second one. More complicated solution : `Promise.all()`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q plz check this

Comment: If i execute first and at end call the second, sometime second one working first

Comment: what does `updateStartJobManual` return?

Comment: and what do these methods actually do?

Comment: You can make use of a [Deffered object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#defer). You can also [chain the promises together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736974/synchronous-and-asynchronous-calling-in-angularjs-with-promise-and-defer) with `$q.all`

Comment: if any of those functions are asynchronous, then, no to your title, you can not make it work synchronously

Comment: See my updated question with all functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual code already executes `updateStartJobManual` and `byeSendManualInputDirectly` synchronously.

However, if your functions are handling promises, both will end prematurely with a background job running. So, let's chain the promises to perform one after another.

Assume your `byeSendManualInputDirectly` (and byeSendManualInputDirectly) is made as such:

```
function byeSendManualInputDirectly(){
   return $http.post('myApiAddress', {myParam: true});
}
```

This way, the function  is returning a promise.

To concatenate `updateStartJobManual` and `byeSendManualInputDirectly` you can simply:

```
updateStartJobManual().then(function(){
   byeSendManualInputDirectly()
});
```

I suggest you to read some articles about promises and to understand how they works (see [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) documentation about usage of $q, the library for promises angularjs uses)

**Edit based on OP's code:**

simply add a return to your function `updateStartJobManual`, this way:

```
function updateStartJobManual() {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        ...
}
```

and in your `saveManualResendDraft`, add a then() to handle the promise:

```
$scope.saveManualResendDraft = function(todo) {
    if ($scope.editMode) 
        updateStartJobManual().then(byeSendManualInputDirectly);
     else 
        console.log('bye');        
};
```

Comment: i Tried this not working correctly, i am beginner to JS, will you post some answers with my code located in question.

Comment: i tried working good, but this hitting two time "
function addProfSms() {
    $http.post('/api/sendprofsms', $scope.draft).then(function(response)  see my quesion i have this function